# Change View Based on whether it is rendering inside List Row

Tags: swift, swiftui

Many built in Apple SwiftUI view's render differently depending on whether they are inside a List. One simple example of this is `NavigationLink`.

E.g. This renders a chevron with black text:

```
struct ContentView_List: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("Some text") {
                Text("Some view")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E.g. This renders a button with blue text:

```
struct ContentView_NoList: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Some text") {
                Text("Some view")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to know whether the current view is being rendered as a row in a list? To allow for more generic implementations that have slightly different designs dependent on whether where it is being rendered.

I tried poking around the environment to see if there were any obvious keys but to no success.

I'm looking to be able to do something like the following:

```
struct ContentView_Custom: View {
    // Fake environment key
    @Environment(\.insideList) var isList: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Some text")
            if isList {
                Spacer()
                Text(">")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you aren't supposed to think in a generic way with cheap View structs just make all the different kinds you need and make use of ViewModifier for reusable styling.

Answer (score -1):

SwiftUI Views are just structs, and as such they are usually pretty cheap to create and recreate.

You are more than welcome to create your own `CustomListView` that can facilitate this. You can start by making the EnvironmentValues and Key for this:

```swift
struct IsInListViewKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isInListView: Bool {
        get { self[IsInListViewKey.self] }
        set { self[IsInListViewKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then create your own custom View:

```swift
struct CustomListView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        List {
            content()
        }
        .environment(\.isInListView, true)
    }
}
```

In that view, you pass the environment into the List which in turn will pass it down into its children. Accessing the value is as simple as:

```swift
@Environment(\.isInListView) var isList: Bool
```

The downside to this is that any View inside of your `CustomListView` will have the environment set to `true`, so to make sure that you are adjusting the state, you will have to keep adjusting the Environment whenever you want it to change:

```swift
.environment(\.isInListView, true)
```